# How do I calculate ECEF X,Y,Z velocities for GPS if I have no satellites

Tags: c#, gps, latitude-longitude, satellite

I'm attempting to simulate a GPS message where know variables are starting location, ending location, speed (m/s), and a bearing (0 - 359 degrees).  How can I calculate the ECEF X, Y, Z velocities with this information when I am not tracking any satellites.

Comment: Don't you also need a time variable?

Comment: Usually this is done by subtracting the start from the stop point (as [X,Y,Z] vectors) and dividing by the time elapsed to obtain the velocity.  Is there something special about your data that would make it any more complicated than that?  (E.g., maybe the travel was not in a Euclidean straight line, but along a spherical geodesic.)

Comment: I'm attempting to calculate the XYZ velocity and give that data to another system.  That system somehow is able to display its bearing and speed (km/hr) from my calculated data.  I know what the speed and bearing is suppose to be, but the remote system displays otherwise, so I'm trying to make sure that I'm calculating correctly or if the remote system is processing it incorrectly.

Comment: Velocity is distance divided by time; you can only obtain distance from the coordinates. Is the time variable in your case a fixed amount, such as a polling rate?

Comment: The time variable is a fixed amount.  I've tested the other system with real GPS and it displays everything correctly, so I'm definetly lead to believe that I'm not calculating something correctly.

Comment: With the given variables mentioned above, is there a way to accurately calculate the X, Y, Z velocities without accounting Doppler shifts of satellites?

Comment: Because you provide two locations, *at which one* do you wish to compute the velocities?  Also, in what coordinate system is the bearing given?  (If it's based on a projected system, a correction to a true bearing may be needed.)

Comment: A GPS message contains where you are (LAT/LON and ECEF X, Y, Z) it also contains X, Y, Z velocities. It's the X, Y, Z velocities given all information mentioned above that I'm trying to calculate without satellites.

Comment: My apologies for posting the same question 3 times, I just feel that I'm not phrasing it correctly.

Comment: Numbers would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the motion is on the surface of the earth.

You have too much information. Given Position 1 and position 2 and the knowledge that you are following a great circle, you can calculate the bearing and distance using the formulas given in the [Aviation Formulary](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#flat)

You were given you the speed in meters/second. You can calculate the XYZ for the two points. Use the delta x, delta y, and delta z, and the time to move from point a to point b to calculate the velocity components.